# Stop network bridging

Tags: network-manager, ethernet, netplan

I am looking for a way to stop user bridging networks, or just only have one active adapter at a time.

In otherwise i don’t want the wifi enabled whilst Ethernet is active and the same reversed.

This is for Ubuntu 20.04

Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Look up how to use a [Network Manager Dispatcher script](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/NetworkManager.html) to detect connections and select adapters. Not simple, but what you are asking is also not simple.

Comment: Thanks, i  will look into it